# For loop strange behavior, BASH

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#! /bin/bash
#N Step Staggered Summation
#Four parameters, NSSS(b,n,mu,p)=NSSS($1,$2,$3,$4)

echo "NSSS(b,n,mu,p)=NSSS($1,$2,$3,$4)"
sigma=$(bc <<< ''$2'*('$4'+1)')
echo "sigma=$sigma"
let n=0
for ((r=0; r <= $4; r++))
    do
        s=$(bc <<< 'scale='$sigma';'$1'*'$3'^'$r'/(10^('$2'*('$r'+1)))')
        echo "$s"
        n=$(bc <<< 'scale='$sigma';('$s'+'$n')/1')
    done
echo "M($1,$2,$3)=" 
bc <<< 'scale='$sigma';'$1'/(10^'$2'-'$3')'
echo "NSSS($1,$2,$3,$4)"
echo "$n" > nsss
cat nsss
```

This is my code, it work fine for $4<=32, but when i choose $4>=33 it tells

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: \
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

This error dissapears when i comment the 13th line, but is pretty necessary to have it, and i can't get the relation between $r and the 13th line
Thanks guys

Comment: Are you expecting us to run the code ourselves, examining all the debug output, when we don't even have the data you're using?

Comment: How are you running the script? What inputs? What is the output when it *does* work? One tip: you are leaving all your parameters unquoted, which can cause hard-to-find errors when it matters. Try, for example, `sigma=$(bc <<< "$2 * ($4 + 1)")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0
```

Put this line at the beginning in your script.